# Setting up max worker process and queue length for .net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, worker-process

We are running performance run to test our .Net Core WEB API's. And, to have better results we have done below settings on IIS Server for WEB API's

QueueLength - 10000
MaxWorkProcess - 2 & 1 respectively (As we have hosted 2 different API projects into same IIS server and using same application pool.)

Above settings we have done on application pool. Our AWS EC2 instance has 4 vCPUs with 8 gb ram in place.

So, our question is do we need to setup this configuration for .net core api's? And, it is going made any different if we try to load concurrent users in the system?

Any help on this appreciated

Comment: What is the "better results" you are looking for? You'd better define that clearly first, or the discussion can be vague.

Comment: @LexLi Got it. Basically, while running the performance run we are experiencing 502, 504 errors. So, we have checked the infra level where CPU usage is 20% only and its not scaled out. Hence thought of to have these configurations to handle concurrent requests

Comment: If those are the things you focused right now, then you are likely on the wrong path. For ASP.NET 4.x, Request Execution/Wait Time are the key, while ASP.NET Core has similar counters, https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/perfmon-for-iis-and-asp-net/ba-p/826721 Performance tuning requires a lot of experience, so you'd better escalate or hire a consultant.

Comment: @LexLi So, by doing above configuration those 502, 504 error will not resolved? As we have read it will support concurrent connection and request and will not slow down the api performance

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.